# Display Specific table cell at specific indexPath.row

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift4

I created 7 `xib` files each with their own `tableCell`. How do I load those `xib` files in certain orders in a `UITableView`? I can not use `if else` statements for this. The cells need to be hard coded to a certain `indexPath.row`

Can I TAG the the `xib` and create a struct with the tags and then load? how would I do that if that's a good idea?

Thanks!

Comment: First register your cells xib with your tableView, then in the [cellForRowAt indexPath] datasource method check indexPath.row condition. And make an enum for the index.

Comment: Okay so register the xib in viewDidLoad for the tableView. Then check my condition in cellForRow, now the enum can be inside the tableViewVC, and I just call the cases in the cellForRowAt indexPath? Sorry for sounding newbish

Comment: Yes right, so as per the conditions you create cell using the reuse identifiers.

Comment: Got it. Thank you!